# Best way for creating dynamic sidebar section in Symfony 1.4

Tags: view, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have few frontend modules which has own sidebar menu link. I want to create those links in actions class of module:

```
  public function preExecute()
  {
    $items['plan/new'] = 'Create Plan';
    $items['plan/index'] = 'Plans Listing';
    $this->getResponse()->setSlot('sidebar', $items);
  }
```

Slot file sidebar.php

```
    #apps/frontend/templates/sidebar.php
    <?php slot('sidebar') ?>
      <ul>
      <?php foreach($items as $url => $title) : ?>
        <li><?php echo link_to($url, $title) ?></li>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      </ul>
    <?php end_slot() ?>
```

layout.php:

```
    <?php if (has_slot('sidebar')): ?>
      <div id="sidebar"><?php include_slot('sidebar') ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

but my output is Array, how can I render my slot?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing slots and partials. In your action, you set your slot to an array, later you call `include_slot`, and the string representation is `Array`, that is correct.

You should pass items via `$this->items = $items`, then in your action see if `isset($items)` is true, and call `include_partial("sidebar", array("items" => $items))` if neccesary. This will look for a file called `_sidebar.php`.

For more detailed information of how this stuff works, read the [Inside the View Layer: Code fragments](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_code_fragments) part of the sf1.4 book.

Comment: if you use main view (layout.php) this: $this->sidebar_menu = $items; just doesn't work ($sidebar_menu is always undefined in layout/php) :/

Comment: Seems like you want a partial but with logic, use a component, that's exactly what they are for.